# Get sound pressure level speaker android

Tags: android, audio

How can i get the song pressure level (decibel or other unit) of the speaker of device? 
I want to know if the speaker is silent or is playing something.
I need to use the ndk? if yes how?

Comment: `I want to know if the speaker is silent or is playing something.` Simply check if the device is or not **mute**. No need to get involved with **Sci-Fi** physics-sensors (no device includes a `dB-meter`, AFAIK).

Comment: Der Golem is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isMusicActive()`

check the android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29